# Mini motor de busca

Tags: php, arquivo, shell

Eu estou a fazer um mini sistema de busca por urls que estão armazenados em um ficheiro.txt, um por linha, o meu problema é a questão da performance pois tenho 5000 urls armazenados (só) e ele já fica lento na procura, no lado servidor tenho:

```
if(isset($_GET['search'])) {
    $urls = array();
    if(trim($_GET['search']) != '') {
        $urls = search_in_urls($_GET['search']);
    }
    echo json_encode($urls);
}
function search_in_urls($search) {
    $file = fopen("urls.txt", "r");
    $urls = array();
    while(!feof($file)){
        $url = fgets($file);
        if (strpos($url, $search) !== false) {
            $urls[] = $url;
        }
    }
    return $urls;
}
```

Vi [esta resposta aceite no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059026/php-check-if-file-contains-a-string) e gostaria de implementa-la, mas como devolver todas as linhas onde seja reconhecido um match com o meu `$search`?

A solução de procura que vi e que gostaria (a não ser que haja melhores opções) de implementar foi:

```
if(exec('grep '.escapeshellarg($search).' ./urls.txt')) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Ou seja, existe alguma forma de não percorrer todas as linhas à procura de um *match* (conjunto de chars igual aquele que escrevi) e devolver essa linha correspondente por inteiro? Ou que pelo menos para que esta busca fique bem mais rápida?

Comment: Você terá que utilizar algum mecanismo de indexação. Isso é apenas para fins de estudo ou é para um sistema real? Pois se for para um sistema real sugiro utilizar ferramentas prontas como elasticsearch.

Comment: É apenas por brincadeira/curiosidade, também sei que a performance seria melhor se tivesse os `urls` armazenados em uma base de dados, seria assim que faria num projeto real. Obgado @ViniciusZaramella

Comment: Boa sorte: http://homepages.dcc.ufmg.br/~nivio/cursos/ri16/transp/indexing.pdf

Comment: Nem há comando shell que possa ser usado? que devolva a(s) linha(s) toda(s) onde haja match? @taiar. Dessa maneira podia injetar o comando no `exec(...`

Comment: O grep que você postou faz exatamente isso. Não consigo saber o resultado que você vai receber em questão de performance. Segundo a documentação http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php você deve passar uma segunda variável "output" na qual será inserida as linhas ele conseguiu encontrar um match.

Comment: @ViniciusZaramella Estávamos com a mesma dúvida, acho que só faltou ele passar um output mesmo. Veja minha resposta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se entendi bem a pergunta, você quer isto:

```
$matches = array();
if(exec('grep '.escapeshellarg($search).' ./urls.txt', $matches)) {
    // $matches contém as linhas encontradas
}
```

Basta passar ao [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) a referência a uma array onde a saída será guardada. E a saída do `grep` são justamente as linhas do arquivo onde houve matches da expressão regular.

Comment: Mas isso devolve a(s) linha(s) por inteiro? . Obgado, já vou testar

Comment: Sim, por inteiro. É como o `grep` funciona.

Comment: Realmente o problema era para onde iam os resultados. Obgado mais uma vez